# UIWebView apparently scrolled after loading content from URL

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint, contentoffset

I am loading an HTML document into a `UIWebView` with `loadRequest:requestURL`. The HTML content does not fit entirely into the view's frame. What surprises me that at the time the page has been loaded (when `webViewDidFinishLoad:`is called) the view's `scrollView.contentOffset` is different from `(0,0)`. It looks as if the content may have been scrolled down approximately so that its vertical center is aligned with the view's vertical center (see screenshot below).

How can this happen and how can I achieve the desired behavior of having the content's top left corner aligned with the view's top left corner initially? Setting `scrollView.contentOffset` to `(0,0)` in webViewDidFinishLoad:` is an option but apparently leads to some flickering.

This is occurring in the context of a `UIViewController` that contains two sibling `UIWebView`s below its root view. The two `UIWebView`s are vertically stacked with a `UILabel` (appears in screenshot with gray background) in between. (The lower `UIWebView` is not visible in the screenshot, because it's currently all white.) The view uses constraint-based layout and the current problem concerns the upper `UIWebView`.

**UPDATE** Further study has revealed that the visual defect is not due to scrolling in the upper `UIWebView` but due to its `frame.origin.y` having been set from `0` to `64` (which is also the combined height of the status bar and the navigation bar) by the time `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called. I am calling `loadRequest:requestWithURL:` from the view controller's `viewWillAppear:` and there is a layout constraint on the upper `UIWebView` that imposes a vertical space of `0` between its top and the bottom of the Top Layout Guide.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens is the following: iOS 7 wants `UIScrollView`s to extend underneath the status and navigation bars when scrolled downwards. Apparently it performs the initial vertical scrolling as a means for preventing the top part of web content from being hidden behind these bars before any scrolling occurs.

I had a layout constraint for a vertical distance of 0 to the top layout guide placed on the `UIWebView` which led to the wrong vertical distance of twice the height of the status bar plus the height navigation bar from the top of the screen. Replacing this layout constraint by one for a vertical distance of 0 from the superview corrected the wrong.